# Parameterized query with dynamic where clasue

Tags: c#, mysql, parameterized-query

So I have this query:

```
var comm = @"SELECT * FROM `TABLE` ";

bool hasWhere = false;

if ( model.Serial > 0 ) {
    comm += " WHERE `SERIAL` LIKE '%" + model.Serial + "%' ";
    hasWhere = true;
}

if ( model.Id.HasValue && model.Id.Value > 0 ) {
    if ( !hasWhere ) {
        comm += " WHERE `NUIP` LIKE '%" + model.Id.Value + "%' ";
        hasWhere = true;
    } else
        comm += " AND `NUIP` LIKE '%" + model.Id.Value + "%' ";
}

if ( model.Date.HasValue ) {
    if ( !hasWhere ) {
        comm += " WHERE `DATE` = '" + model.Date.Value + "' ";
        hasWhere = true;
    } else
        comm += " AND `DATE` = '" + model.Date.Value + "' ";
}
....
....
....
```

I've read about parameterized queries against SQL Injection and so on. The thing is, given that I'll have a dynamic number of WHERE clauses (based on the search model),how can I parameterize the query? I can't put `WHERE a = @A AND b=@B...` because the user must not need to search based on all the columns.

Any idea? thanks in advance.

**P.S:** Can't use LINQ or something similar to that (-business rules-).

Comment: The business rules dictate the implementation? Those don't sound like business rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can still use SQL parameterized query with where close (WHERE will be sort of dynamic). For example I have paramater @SerialNum that is NULL and I have a parameter @Code that equals to 455.

```
SELECT
     Column1
    ,Column2
FROM 
     YourTable
WHERE
    (
        @SerialNum IS NULL
        OR
        Column3 LIKE '%' + @SerialNum + '%'
    )
    AND
    (
        @Code IS NULL
        OR
        Column4 LIKE '%' + @Code + '%'
    )
```

Comment: this is the easiest way, avoiding if statements in the program code.

Comment: Personally I think this better than my way as it is all in the SQL engine! But can you update the code for MYSQL?

Comment: @fenix2222 Brilliant! Absolutely brilliant. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I use this trick.

```
....
WHERE 1 = 1 
AND a = a 
AND b= @b 
AND c = c 
... etc....
```

ie I compare the column to it self if I don't want to search

```
var comm = @"SELECT * FROM `TABLE` WHERE 1 = 1 ";  

if ( model.Serial > 0 ) {  
    comm += " AND  `SERIAL` LIKE '%" + model.Serial + "%' ";  
}  else  {
      comm += " AND  `SERIAL` = `SERIAL`";
}


if ( model.Id.HasValue && model.Id.Value > 0 ) {    
    comm += " AND  `AND` LIKE '%" + model.Id.Value + "%' ";    
}  else  {
       comm += " AND `NUIP` = `NUIP` ";    
}   
....
```

`WHERE 1 = 1` is optimised away and removes the need to remember if a WHERE is defined yet or not,  and all the searches are either optimised away (`AND a=a`) or have search applied (`AND a = xxx`).

You just add a single `if` for each search!

Also I'd use a StringBuilder to clean up the string handling.

Comment: +1 for the removal of that where! any idea about the question indeed (the parameterized version of it). Thanks